# How to activate Codemirror addons in JupyterLab extensions?

Tags: typescript, codemirror, jupyter-lab

I'm writing an extension for JupyterLab and want to modify the settings of the CodeMirror instance in it to activate the addons for hints and match-highlighter. How can I achieve this?

It is for JupyterLab v1.0.1 and I already managed to write an extension which adds custom buttons and functionality at the top bar, depending on the kernel used. Even a custom mode with syntax highlighting I achieved in codemirror.

This is how I define my custom styling for the MIME "xyz", where STATES are matching regex expressions.

```js
import * as CodeMirror from 'codemirror';
import 'codemirror/addon/mode/simple';

export function defineVadalogMode() {
    (CodeMirror as any).defineSimpleMode(MODE_NAME, STATES);
    CodeMirror.defineMIME("text/xyz", MODE_NAME);
    CodeMirror.modeInfo.push({
        ext: FILE_EXTENSIONS,
        mime: MIME,
        mode: MODE_NAME,
        name: NAME
  });
}
```

So I want to include the following packages:

```js
import 'codemirror/addon/hint/show-hint';
import 'codemirror/addon/search/match-highlighter.js';
```

Normally it would suffice to import them and call something like

```js
editor.setOption("highlightSelectionMatches", true);
```

But as I am writing a JupyterLab extension I do not not know how to access this editor object, since I am not creating it, but JupyterLab does.